# How to store data through the life of a shared library

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, singleton, shared-libraries

I'm writing a shared library in C++ which will be called through `JNI`. I have a class which receives messages from Java and forwards to the appropriate object. Let's call it `Dispatcher`. There is a `DataStore` which must exist through the life of the program. Actually some data must be accessible between `JNI` calls.

My current sketch consists of the two classes as singletons. `DataStore` looks like this:

```
class DataStore {
    // constructors, get_instance() etc. are skipped
    int _read_only_variable{};
public:
    DataStore (int param) : _read_only_variable(param) {}
    // or
    void set_data(int param) {
        _read_only_variable = param
    }
};
```

How can I guarantee that only a `Dispatcher` object can create a `DataStore` object or only `Dispatcher` can call `set_data`?

From the other side if I guarantee that the `_read_only_variable` is really written only in the constructor what will make sure that only one instance exists.

I also want to fit `SOLID` principle thus I would avoid nested classes.

Comment: `DataStore` and `Dispatcher` are both c++ classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can guarantee that only `Dispatcher` calls these methods by making them private, and then making `Dispatcher` a `friend`.

P.S. a `_read_only_variable` would be `const` in C++. The compiler will loudly complain of you try to modify it. But it only guarantees that there is one `_read_only_variable` *per  Datastore*, which is pretty trivial and not what you wanted.

Comment: @NjamNjam: That `private` in the class is redundant, class members are private by default.

Comment: yep, anyway i prefer it because it explicitly states that you want this constructor to be private and makes it imho more readable and maintainable